# C# Directory Services is fast but reading the results is really slow

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I am running the following code for all groups in my Active Directory.

What I am trying to do is first run a query to get all groups in my Active Directory and return their distinguished names. Following which I am using the code below to get a list of all subgroups in each group. This includes nested subgroups. The code is working, albeit its really slow.

The LDAP queries always execute extremely fast, but when I am trying to work with the result, it is extremely slow. Is there anything I can use to speed up this process?

Currently it takes me around 2 hrs to execute around 20000 groups it looks like. (I have over 2 million in my AD).

Following is the code I use:

**Getting All Groups**

```
public override IEnumerable<ADGroupObj> GetCustomGroupAndMember(ADSetting setting)
{
    var m_strADFilter = configHandler.GetCustomGroupFilterString().ToString();
    string classAndMethodName = $"{this.GetType().Name}.{MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name}";
    string[] properties = { "objectGUID", "cn", "distinguishedName", "member", "objectSid" };

    //group
    m_log.DebugFormat("[{0}]: [GetAllGroupAndMemberFromDomainController] m_strADFilter = {1}", classAndMethodName, m_strADFilter);
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(m_strADFilter))
    {
        string strErrorMsg = string.Format("[{0}]: Incorrect AD filter string !!!", classAndMethodName);
        m_log.ErrorFormat(strErrorMsg);
        throw new Exception(strErrorMsg);
    }

    bool isSuccess = false;

    using (ADServerWrapper instADServer = ADServerWrapper.GetADServerWrapper(setting, this.ConnectType))
    {
        int iTotalCount = 0;
        int iInvalidCount = 0;
        int iValidCount = 0;

        var results = instADServer.QueryADbyFilterObj(m_strADFilter, properties);
        if (results == null)
        { throw new Exception("Error occured while invoking instADServer.QueryADbyFilterObj."); }

        (var whiteListDomainOUs, var blackListDomainOUs) = configHandler.GetADSpecifyDomainOU();
        foreach (SearchResult result in results)
        {
            ++iTotalCount;

            // Check Result valid or not
            ADGroupObj adGroup = AnalyzeADGroupObj(result.Properties, whiteListDomainOUs, blackListDomainOUs);
            adGroup = GetAllGrpMembers(adGroup,setting);
            if (adGroup != null && ValidateADGroup(adGroup))
            {
                ++iValidCount;
                configHandler.UpdateCustomGroupDN(adGroup.DN);
                yield return adGroup;
                m_log.DebugFormat("[{0}]: AD Group ([Valid]/[total] count=[{1}]/[{2}]): {3}", classAndMethodName, iValidCount, iTotalCount, adGroup.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                ++iInvalidCount;
                m_log.DebugFormat("[{0}]: AD Group ([Null or inValid]/[total] count={1}/{2})", classAndMethodName, iInvalidCount, iTotalCount);
            }
        }

        isSuccess = true;
    }

    if (!isSuccess)
    {
        string strErrorMsg = string.Format("[{0}]: Did not complete successfully, isSuccess == false.", classAndMethodName);
        m_log.ErrorFormat(strErrorMsg);
        throw new Exception(strErrorMsg);
    }
}
```

**Getting All SubGroups**

```
protected ADGroupObj GetAllGrpMembers(ADGroupObj aDGroup, ADSetting setting) {
    string methodName = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
    var forUserConnectType = ADServiceConnectType.AD_CONNECT_TYPE_GC | (this.connectType & ADServiceConnectType.AD_CONNECT_TYPE_SSL);
    var instADServer = ADServerWrapper.GetADServerWrapper(setting, forUserConnectType);
    string m_strADFilter = $"(&(objectCategory=group)(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={aDGroup.DN}))";
    string[] properties = {
            "distinguishedName"
        };
    try
    {
        aDGroup.Members = new List<string>();
        IEnumerable<SearchResult> results = instADServer.QueryADbyFilterObj(m_strADFilter, properties);
        if (results != null)
        {

            foreach (SearchResult result in results)
            {
               if (result.Properties["distinguishedName"] != null && result.Properties["distinguishedName"].Count > 0)
                {
                    var user = result.Properties["distinguishedName"][0];
                    aDGroup.Members.Add(user.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        else
            m_log.DebugFormat("[{0}]:No value with member attribute!", methodName);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {


    }
    return aDGroup;
}
```

Here the foreach result column in both is what takes the most time. not the Query AD By Filter Obj.

For Reference:
**QueruADByFilterObj**

```
public IEnumerable<SearchResult> QueryADbyFilterObj(string strFilter, string[] properties)
{
    using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(m_ADEntryObject))
    {
        searcher.Filter = strFilter;
        searcher.SizeLimit = int.MaxValue;
        searcher.PageSize = int.MaxValue;
        searcher.CacheResults = false;
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(properties);
        //searcher.ReferralChasing = ReferralChasingOption.All;

        using (SearchResultCollection searchResults = searcher.FindAll())
        {
            foreach (SearchResult result in searchResults)
            {
                yield return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing it going to take a long time. You're pulling a lot of data.

I wrote an article about getting [better performance](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html) when programming with AD, but it seems you're already doing what I would have recommended when searching (making sure to use `PropertiesToLoad`). But it still looks like there is some code you haven't shared here, so you can review that and see if there's anything else you can tweak.

It takes a long time to read the results because the results come in pages. You're setting `PageSize` to `int.MaxValue`, but AD will never return more that 1000 results at a time. So the results will be sent to you in pages of 1000. That means that when you try to process result 1001, it will pause, go out to AD and get the next page of results. Same thing at 2001, 3001, etc.

It also might help to know why you're pulling all this data in the first place. It seems odd to store it all somewhere else when it's already in AD. But I know you might have just been told to do it.... it's happened to me.

As a side note, have you read about [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) in C#? It can make your `string.Format` lines much easier to read. For example, this line:

```
string strErrorMsg = string.Format("[{0}]: Incorrect AD filter string !!!", classAndMethodName);
```

Could be simplified to this:

```
var strErrorMsg = $"[{classAndMethodName}]: Incorrect AD filter string !!!";
```

Comment: Actually, very few groups or subgroups have members larger than 1500. While debugging, what I've noticed is that the most time seems to be taken when trying to iterate through the values stored in result.

Comment: Sorry, it's 1000, not 1500 (the 1500 limit applies when pulling values from a multi-value attribute). I think it's worth a try to set `PageSize` to `1000` and don't set `SizeLimit` and see if you have any different results. If not, then see if you can figure out which line of code is taking longer than others. The newest versions of Visual Studio will show you how long the last line of code took when you step through.